# Automatic insertion of \item in Sublime Text 2

Tags: lists, editors

Is there a way to automatically insert `\item` whenever I hit enter within an `itemize` or `enumerate` in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that `itemize` and `enumerate` was _really_ code.

Comment: Marking them as code makes it clear that you are speaking about environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the LaTeXTools plugin, it already does that exept that it is mapped on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The corresponding code is in the `default (PLATFORM).sublime-keymap`

```
// automatic addition of new \items when hitting Shift+Enter in a list environment
{ "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\\item $0"}, 
"context":  
    [
        {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "meta.function.environment.list.latex"},
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

You can duplicate it or modify it in order to map it on another key by replacing the content inside of the first brackets after "keys"

Comment: Thanks! But when I change `"shift+enter"` to `"enter"`, pressing `enter` right after `\end{itemize}` still inserts `\item`? Is that just a small glitch?

Comment: @AlfredXing  
I never noticed this but you are right. It is less annoying with the original shortcut. Maybe that's why they did not choose enter !

Comment: @AlfredXing Tried to dig into this and ended up by opening a thread on ST2 forum to try to know more about this:
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10270&p=40662#p40662

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the LaTeX Tools package, hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> within any sort of list environment will insert new `\item`s (if you're not, you really should be). If you want change this to just <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you'll have to change the user keybindings (Preferences > Package Settings > LaTeXTools > Keybindings – User).